# Selenium how to click an <a> tag with in a <div> with the bootstrap drop down class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am new to Selenium and I'm having an issue clicking on a link in a bootstrap dropdown.  Here's the markup:

```
<div class="dropdown float-lg-right">
    <button class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" 
         data-toggle="dropdown">Select Action
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/controller/action?id=123">Add/Update Status</a>
            <button class="dropdown-item">Edit</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item">Send Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the current code attempting to execute a click on the Add/Update Status link:

```
public static By addUpdateStatusDropDown = By.Id("dropdownMenuButton");
public static By addUpdateStatus = By.XPath("//*[contains(.,'Add/Update Status')]");

public void AddUpdateStatusClick()
{
    //This does expand the drop down
    _wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(addUpdateStatusDropDown )).JSClick(driver);

    //This does not select the <a>Add/Update Status</a> tag
    _wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(addUpdateStatus )).JSClick(driver);    
}
```

An additional note.  This drop down exists in a table cell so there will be multiple rows that have a link with the Add/Update Status text.  I'm only interested in selecting the first one in the first row.

Can someone please help me figure out how to simulate a click on the Add/Update Status link within the dropdown?

Comment: Can you try with following xpath `//div[@class='dropdown float-lg-right']//div[@class='dropdown-menu']/a[text()='Add/Update Status']`

Answer (score 0):

As it is a [Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/) element, instead of `ElementIsVisible` you need to use [ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable Method (By)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) as follows:

```
public static By addUpdateStatusDropDown = By.Id("dropdownMenuButton");
public static By addUpdateStatus = By.XPath("//div[@class='dropdown-menu']/a[@class='dropdown-item' and contains(.,'Add/Update Status')]");

public void AddUpdateStatusClick()
{
    //This does expand the drop down
    _wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(addUpdateStatusDropDown )).JSClick(driver);

    //This does not select the <a>Add/Update Status</a> tag
    _wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(addUpdateStatus )).JSClick(driver);    
}
```